# How can I authenticate with Cognito and AWS_IAM in karate?

Tags: amazon-iam, karate, aws-signature

I'm trying to test an Appsync API protected by AWS_IAM and Cognito identity provider. To be authorised, I need to use AWS Signature v4. Is there anyway I could intercept HTTP requests and set the headers (with the help of an external library, potentially a JavaScript library) ?

Comment: see linked answer. do try it out and we can make more changes to karate if needed